# How to solve a PDE problem by Fourier series method?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I made the following about Fourier series:

```
eo = Integrate[(Cos[Pi*x])^2, {x, 0, 1}]
en := 2*Integrate[(Cos[Pi*x])^2*Cos[n*Pi*x], {x, 0, 1}]
ca = Table[en, {n, 1, 20}]
ListPlot[ca]
v[x_, t_, N_] := eo + Sum[en*Cos[Pi*n*x]*E^[-(n^2)*(Pi^2)*t], {n, 1, N}]
v[x, t, 20]
ContourPlot[v[x, t, 20], {x, 0, Pi}, {t, 0, 0.5}, 
ColorFunction \[RightArrow] "DarkRainbow"]
u[x_, t_, b_, N_] := v[x, t, N]*E^[b*x]
u[x, t, b, 20]
ContourPlot[u[x, t, 5, 20], {x, 0, Pi}, {t, 0, 0.5}, 
ColorFunction \[RightArrow] "DarkRainbow"]
```

but it seems not to work, and I can't understand the reason. 
I was trying to solve $ v_t=v_{xx}$ with $ v_x(0,t)=v_x(1,t)=0, v(x,0)=(\cos {(\pi x)})^2, 0<x<1,t >0.$ I calculated analytically and show the results with the partial sums, that is my goal.
Any help?

Comment: Not sure what you are doing here. Are you trying to calculate the Fourier series for Cos^2 over half a period? There are built-in routines for Fourier.

Comment: I was trying to solve: $v_t=v_{xx}$ with $v_x(0,t)=v_x(1,t)=0, v[x,0]=(\cos {(\pi x)})^2, 0<x<1,t >0.$ I calculated analytically and show the results, that is my goal

Comment: There're multiple simple mistakes. 1. `\[RightArrow]` should be `->`, notice they're different. 2. The `E^[` should be e.g. `Exp[`. 3. `{x,0,Pi}` should be `{x,0,1}`. 4. If the `ListPlot` doesn't even work, consider `Clear[x,n]` at the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

Mathematica solves your PDE with the boundary and initial conditions by

```
sol = DSolve[{D[v[x, t], t] == D[v[x, t], {x, 2}], Derivative[1, 0][v][0, t] == 0, 
Derivative[1, 0][v][1, t] == 0, v[x, 0] == Cos[Pi*x^2]^2}, v[x,t], {x, t}]

(* {{v[x, t] ->  1/4 (2 + FresnelC[2]) + 
2 Inactive[Sum][ 1/8 E^(-\[Pi]^2 t K[1]^2)
    Cos[\[Pi] x K[
      1]] (Cos[1/8 \[Pi] K[1]^2] FresnelC[2 - K[1]/2] + 
     Cos[1/8 \[Pi] K[1]^2] FresnelC[
       1/2 (4 + K[1])] + (FresnelS[2 - K[1]/2] + 
        FresnelS[1/2 (4 + K[1])]) Sin[1/8 \[Pi] K[1]^2]), {K[1], 
   1, \[Infinity]}]*)
```

In order to visualize the solution,

```
asol = v[x, t] /. sol[[1]] /. {\[Infinity] -> 3} // Activate;
Plot3D[asol // Evaluate, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2}, Exclusions -> None, 
PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]

PS. It seems you changed the initial condition from $\cos(x^2))^2$ to $\cos(x)^2$. In this case

```
DSolve[{D[v[x, t], t] == D[v[x, t], {x, 2}], Derivative[1, 0][v][0, t] == 0, Derivative[1, 0][v][1, t] == 0, v[x, 0] == Cos[Pi*x]^2}, v[x, t], {x, t}]
(*{{v[x, t] -> 1/2 (1 + E^(-4 \[Pi]^2 t) Cos[2 \[Pi] x])}}*)
```

Comment: I need to show the partial sums, as I tried and plot them

Comment: I added that in response to your additional request.

Comment: Thank you, I preffer an answer about my original question

Comment: @George: You missed the minus sign in E^[(n^2)*(Pi^2)*t].

Comment: that is right. But ca and the ListPlot doesn't work, and so the others command and I don;t know the reason